# rails 7 with sprockets, enable origin file in compiled css in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I just started a new rails 7 project with --css bootstrap, but I'm finding that starting the server with `bin/dev` the compiled css does no longer (as in previous rails versions) output a comment with the file name and line number of the file where to find each scss class definition.

I'm actually rather confused on how the new rails works with scss and css, it doesn't seem that the css is compiled at all. I couldn't find any good resources for understanding how it works. any suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: If this solved the problem could you mark as accepted. Would help other people running into this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sprockets doesn't seem to generate sourcemaps by default.
You can try opening up this file:
`config/environments/development.rb`

And adding the line:
`config.assets.debug = true`

Answer (score 0):

What are the contents of you `din/dev` file?

Also rails 7 got rid of webpack:

> Webpacker has served the Rails community for over five years as a
> bridge to compiled and bundled JavaScript. This bridge is no longer
> needed for most people in most situations following the release of
> Rails 7. We now have three great default answers to JavaScript in
> 2021+, and thus we will no longer be evolving Webpacker in an official
> Rails capacity.

Rails 7 now uses [importmaps](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails), so depending on your gem file you might have to use [css-bundling](https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails). Look into that and [dartsass](https://github.com/rails/dartsass-rails) along  with [propshaft](https://github.com/rails/propshaft), which replaces sprockets which they are thinking about doing in the future, to get a better idea.

> **Will Propshaft replace Sprockets as the Rails default?** Most likely,
> but Sprockets need to be supported as well for a long time to come.
> Plenty of apps and gems were built on Sprocket features, and they
> won't be migrating soon. Still working out the compatibility story.
> This is very much alpha software at the moment.

Comment: The original poster said they were using sprockets, not webpack. That seems to be the default for rails 7, even though it was made into an optional dependency. This answer doesn't solve their problem about how to tell sprockets not to compile their application.css, or add file/line comments, so they can better debug their css